# Google Chrome filling Fedora syslog

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, syslog

Fedora 20 (was also happening on Fedora 19 before I upgraded last week), Google Chrome (stable) package `google-chrome-stable-37.0.2062.120-1.x86_64`.

My `/var/log/messages` file is getting filled with tons of messages of this format:

```
Sep 17 11:21:38 xxxxxx /etc/gdm/Xsession[15691]: [14334:14836:0917/112138:ERROR:value_store_frontend.cc(62)] Error while writing pkehgijcmpdhfbdbbnkijodmdjhbjlgp.browser_action to /home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extension State
```

That directory looks like this:

```
$ ls -la '/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extension State'
total 37236
drwxrwx---.  2 user user    4096 Sep 17 11:25 .
drwx------. 18 user user    4096 Sep 17 11:25 ..
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user    2422 May  7  2013 000473.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user  383609 May  9  2013 000475.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user  452513 May 10  2013 000478.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user  611630 May 10  2013 000481.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4023516 May 14  2013 000484.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4174557 May 16  2013 085503.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4176130 May 17  2013 168720.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4176130 May 21  2013 207630.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user  654387 May 22  2013 207632.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4174557 May 23  2013 286790.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 3369565 May 29  2013 286792.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4174557 May 30  2013 311947.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 3517042 Jun  3  2013 311949.sst
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user 4191834 Jun  5  2013 311953.log
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user      16 Jun  3  2013 CURRENT
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user       0 Aug 15  2012 LOCK
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user user       0 Sep 17 11:25 LOG
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user user       0 Sep 17 11:25 LOG.old
-rwxrwx---.  1 user user    1867 Jun  4  2013 MANIFEST-311951
```

SELinux is in `permissive` mode, and all of the above have context `unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0`.

There's nothing relevant in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, and I haven't found anything about this online.  (Yet, at least.)

Has anyone seen this/know what's causing it/know what to do about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For me, simply deleting the contents of the 'Extension State' directory didn't have any deleterious effects, and seems to have fixed the problem.  I'm not sure what those files are for, perhaps a temporary state cache for extensions (Doing nothing but switching tabs causes the error/files to be written), but they don't seem to be particularly important to save.

I suspect the problem gets caused if the system is shutdown improperly or Chrome crashes and it gets left in an odd state.

Comment: This worked like a charm, and not just for removing silly warnings, but also making things behave well again.

Comment: renaming `Extension State` do `Extension State old` fixed the problem. Chrome created new `Extension State` folder.